# How to identify a project (eclipse) type (RCP or other) to look at the code?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Please bear with me, if my question sounds bad.

I am working with a project (java eclipse), I had the code base in my office laptop, it works fine, now I need to get inside the code/project so that I can modify when needed.

I can code in java (intermediate level), but I am a beginner at eclipse stuff, specially eclipse application/plugins.

I am spending lots of time reading/watching different tutorials on eclipse (like vogella, o7planning, help.eclipse, etc.) but got confused on all these different stuff, RCP, SWT/jFace, Java GUI, windowbuilder, etc.

I need to know How "this" (my project that I'm working) got started? Is it a eclipse RCP? seems like a RCP, but there is no OSGi,

Here is a list of what it has (other than `.java, JRE library, Plug-in dependencies`),

```
META-INF, build.properties, a product file, a launch, h2 connectivity, a plugin.xml
```

From user point of view, this program has several menus, views,

I was able to open some views in windowbuilder editor (not all views/menus)

some java classes named as handler (part of name).

**Any suggestions (reading materials) how to start with this project to understand it completely will be really helpful.**

**Is there any way to reproduce the whole project (using all the codes/java files that I already have)?**

Comment: A plugin.xml makes it an Eclipse plug-in, having a xxx.product file as well makes it the main plug-in for an Eclipse RCP (but there may be other plug-ins as well).

Comment: @greg-449, thanks a lot, how should I approach/start to understand this type of project? please.

Comment: I'm afraid there is quite a steep learning curve here. It would probably make sense to go through one of the Eclipse RCP tutorials from vogella.com to get an idea of how things fit together. If the project has an Application.e4xmi file it is an [tag:e4] RCP (https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html), if not it is probably a Eclipse 3 compatability mode RCP (https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse3RCP/article.html)

Comment: It doesn't has any Application.e4xmi. The eclipse ide is 2018-12, I did follow https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html that article. I was thinking, if I could rebuild the whole project by myself (since I have all the required code/classes) that would build my confidence. Any suggestions to do this. Thank you so much. @greg-449

Comment: Modern builds use [tag:maven] + [tag:tycho] in which case there will be a pom.xml. Otherwise it may be using the old Ant based build or just using 'File > Export > Plug-in Development > Eclipse product'

Comment: @greg-449 Right clicking on project (from package explorer) and selecting Configure  shows a menu with , Convert to Xtext Project, Convert to Facted Form, Add graddle Nature, Create module-info.java, Convert to Javascript project, add bndtools, convert to Maven Project.

Comment: the project has following dependencies, org.eclipse.ui, org.eclipse.core.runtime and org.h2 (this is for database I understood)

Comment: None of which are anything to do with building the RCP. I'm sorry but this is way too broad for Stack Overflow, you really do have to work through some RCP/plug-in development tutorials

Answer (score 1):

One way to do reverse engineering is by going through plugin.xml.

vogella is a good tutorial you will find all major eclipse rcp related tutorials.

You mentioned menu go through your plugin.xml you will find org.eclipse.ui.menus extension and associated handlers. 
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html

Do your plugin project contains.xtend files go through https://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation/101_gettingstarted.html

Do your plugin project contains xtext files go through DSL
https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/102_domainmodelwalkthrough.html